# RcppArmadillo sample on armadillo vector classes

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

We have been using the `sample` function from `RcppArmadillo` to randomly sample a `NumericVector` object. However, we have noticed that it isn't possible to use the same function on Armadillo types (`vec` or `uvec`). We have looked at the function definitions from the `sample.h` file and it looks like a templated function that should be able to work with these types, but we haven't been able to figure out how to make it work with Armadillo classes without doing a lot of conversions to and from the `NumericVector` or `IntegerVector` types from the `Rcpp` library.

For example, we have this function written in a file called `try.cpp`.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec sample_index(const int &size){
    arma::uvec sequence = linspace<uvec>(0, size-1, size);
    arma::uvec out = sample(sequence, size, false);
    return out;
}
```

Running the code above yields the following errors:

```
src/try.cpp|11 col 22 error| no matching function for call to 'sample' [cpp/gcc]      

~/Library/R/3.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h|401 col 1 error| note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'arma::uvec' (aka 'Col<unsigned int>') to 'int' for 1st argument [cpp/gcc]

~/Library/R/3.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h|437 col 1 error| note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Vector' against 'Col' [cpp/gcc]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: could you quickly confirm the version of RcppArmadillo is the latest? `sessionInfo()` >=7.6

Comment: Output from `sessionInfo()`: `RcppArmadillo_0.7.700.0.0`

Comment: As a first (defensive) step, undo `using namespace ...` as we now have _two_ `sample` functions.

Comment: Tried commenting out the two `using namespace` lines and got more errors. Also tried with only one of each commented out and still got errors. However, specifically typing out each namespace in front of everything, I was able to get it working, but the `sample` function needs to be called as `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(sequence, size, false)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this problem in the future, the problem seems to have something to do with multiple definitions of the `sample` function in the namespaces being used. Specifically typing out the namespaces where the required function is defined solves the problem. In particular, the `sample` function needs to be called from `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo`.

The following code works as desired.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec sample_index(const int &size){
    arma::uvec sequence = arma::linspace<arma::uvec>(0, size-1, size);
    arma::uvec out = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(sequence, size, false);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `namespace` declarations at the top of the file please. You are not using them. And this will likely bite others who copy and paste code.

Comment: I would reword this to: "Given that there are now two `sample()` implementations in both the `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo` namespaces (with the latter still optional), you need to be more explicit about which you select."

Comment: Linking to related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44060134/1169233