# "RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h" Linker Error in R Package Build Step

Tags: rcpp, armadillo, r-package

I am making an R package which uses the `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample()` function in some of the source files. In particular, I use that function in 4 different cpp files and in each one of them I add this line `#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>` to include the required header file.

Everything works fine until when I want to build the package by the command `R CMD build mypackage`. I get the **duplicate symbol** error where most of the functions defined in the mentioned header file are listed as the duplicated symbols. For instance, functions like `ProbSampleNoReplace`, `FixProb`, `SampleReplace` and `WalkerProbSampleReplace` are all listed as duplicated between those 4 cpp files.

I googled this problem and the solution is to define the variables or functions in the `.cpp` file instead of the `.h` file to prevent duplication, and use `extern` if you want to use those variables in any other `cpp` files. But I think that solution does not apply here as the header file is not written by me and I don't want to make any changes to the `sample.h` header file located [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h).

Any suggestion how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to show your code. This isn't reproducible.

Comment: "In particular, I use that function in 4 different cpp files". You can't. It can only be in one file.

Comment: Each of those 4 cpp files have different purposes and all of them need that function. So I guess you're suggesting to merge them into one file. I thought there should be another way. Thanks Dirk.

Comment: You can only include the header _once_. If you need the functionality in different places, write an access function you call from the four files.  But only one `#include` of the `sample()` file.

Comment: Great! that actually worked! I initially thought it is the same as other `#include` lines that can be added at the beginning of every cpp file. 
Anyways, you saved me as always. Thanks a lot Dirk!

Comment: @AmirNik, care to share your solution as an official answer? I'm having the same problem and would love to see what you've done in more detail.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio, thanks for reminding me. I just shared my solution as an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked for me based on Dirk's comments:

I removed redundant headers on top of each file and put it in one place. This can be done in two ways. One is to put it in one access function that can be called anywhere needed.

Another option is that if your whole project is not that big, you can put the header `#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>` on top of the main `.cpp` file, which contains your project with multiple functions. I actually did the latter option for my own project.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the first option stated by @amir-nik in his answer no Jun 16, 2021.

> One is to put it in one access function that can be called anywhere needed.

As it took me quite some time to figure out how to do it, I provide a full example here in case it is of interest to anyone.

First, I made the following source file `sample.cpp`. The overloading is because I need the sampling function to work on two different vector types.

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
arma::vec sample(const arma::vec& x, const int& size, const bool& replace, const arma::vec& probs){
  return Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(x, size, replace, probs);
}
arma::uvec sample(const arma::uvec& x, const int& size, const bool& replace, const arma::vec& probs){
  return Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(x, size, replace, probs);
}
```

Next, I made this header file `sample.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
arma::vec sample(const arma::vec& x, const int& size, const bool& replace, const arma::vec& probs);
arma::uvec sample(const arma::uvec& x, const int& size, const bool& replace, const arma::vec& probs);
#endif
```

Now, by writing `#include "sample.h"` I can use `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample()` in all of my code.