# Generate random index from Armadillo vector

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I am looking to generate a random index from a given armadillo vector (using the Rcpp interface from R). The function I am using is as follows:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int index_rand(arma::vec& v) {

  arma::uvec indices; 

  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.n_elem; ++i) {

    indices[i] = i;

  }

  arma::uvec u = RcppArmadillo::sample(indices, 1, false);
  return u[0];
}
```

However, this code complies but crashes the R interpreter when running:

```
index_rand(1:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a tricky issue solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353109/rcpparmadillo-sample-on-armadillo-vector-classes?rq=1). The answer is as follows for posterity.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int index_rand(arma::vec& v) {

  arma::uvec indices = arma::linspace<arma::uvec>(0, v.n_elem-1, v.n_elem); 

  arma::uvec u = RcppArmadillo::sample(indices, 1, false);
  return (int)u[0];
}
```

Comment: Note that `arma::uvec` is an `unsigned int` yet you assign and return an `int`.  You may want to cast that,

Comment: Edited to reflect this suggestion