# sample in Rcpp Armadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am currently struggeling with the sample() command provided in `RcppArmadillo`. When I try to run the code below I get the error `no matching function for call to sample` and I already add the extra `Rcpp::` namespace in front since this worked out well in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353109/rcpparmadillo-sample-on-armadillo-vector-classes).

I also tried several other container classes, but I am always stuck with this error. Below is some code, which produces the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix example(arma::mat fprob,
                      int K) {
  int t = fprob.n_rows;
  IntegerVector choice_set = seq_len(K);
  arma::mat states(t,1); states.fill(0);
  arma::rowvec p0(K);
  arma::rowvec alph(K);
  double fit;

  p0 = fprob.row(t-1);
  fit = accu(p0);
  alph = p0/fit;
  states(t-1,1) = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(choice_set, 1, false, alph)[0];

  return wrap(states);
}
```

Comment: `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample`??

Comment: I am pretty sure this question is also a duplicate...  So if someone has a minute to search for it we could probably close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the definition of that function from the header:

```cpp
    // Enables supplying an arma probability
    template <class T> 
    T sample(const T &x, const int size, const bool replace, arma::vec &prob_){
      return sample_main(x, size, replace, prob_);
    }
```

Note that it expects a `arma::vec == arma::colvec`, while you are providing a `arma::rowvec`. So it should work if you change `p0` and `alph` to `arma::vec`. Untested because of missing sample data ...

BTW, there is meanwhile also a `Rcpp:::sample()` function in case you are not really needing Armadillo for other tasks.

Concerning the performance questions raised by @JosephWood in the comments:
I have the impression that both [`Rcpp::sample()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h) and [`Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h) are based on [`do_sample()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3c8a64a5cbd08e8c2d920011bd02b07914792b45/src/main/random.c#L451). So they should be quite similar in most cases, but I have not benchmarked them. The higher performance of R for unweighted sampling without replacement for larger numbers comes from the [hash algorithm](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d8279508eb30d9ce61c75f45190901f2a4d77be5/src/main/unique.c#L1794), which is [selected at R level](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/base/R/sample.R#L30) in such cases. It is also interesting to note that R 3.6 will have a new method for sampling in order to remove a bias present in the current method.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I'm pretty new to rcpp, so thanks for the advice.

Comment: It should be noted that `Rcpp::sample` is bounded by integers whereas `sample` from base R can accept numbers as large as 4e15. Also, the base R sample is much faster when the input is greater than 1e7.

Comment: @JosephWood And `Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample()` is comparable to `Rcpp::sample()` in both respects, right?

Comment: @RalfStubner, I think so. Right after I wrote that comment I went straight to the source code for Arma and Rcpp and they look very similar. Interestingly enough, the benchmarks I did were simply guess and check. I.e. I measured sampling 100 numbers with a max size of 1e5, 1e6, and 1e7 and they were nearly identical timings. When I tried 1e8, the timing difference was around 10000 times faster for base R.

Comment: Also, in the source code for arma, we see that there is a check for numbers larger than 1e7 https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/66fe84bc6993b6225e5d49cb2eac81e5e923cf3a/inst/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h#L80. Lastly, I was hoping you would know as I know you are bit of a random number expert. To that end, thanks for all of your contributions.

Comment: @JosephWood I had looked at the different sampling methods, but did not remember the details. I just refreshed m memory and updated the answer with my (current) understanding.